# jquery highlight image by click

Tags: jquery

I have 2 questions:

1. I'm using this code: http://jsfiddle.net/9rFKB/

as you can see when I click on some image its getting bold border, and field "size" get the name of the image. how can I get the image ID value?

1. when I load the page I want that the chosen image to be already with bold border. what do I need to add?

Thanks!

```
<p id="thumbs">
    <input type="hidden" name="size"> 

    <img src='images/size1.png' id='1' />
    <img src='images/size2.png' id='2' />
    <img src='images/size3.png' id='3' />
    <img src='images/size4.png' id='4' />               

</p>



<script>
$('#thumbs').delegate('img', 'click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    $('#thumbs img').removeClass('border-highlight');


    $this.addClass('border-highlight');


    $('[name="size"]').val( $this.attr('src').substring($this.attr('src').lastIndexOf('/')+1) );
//    alert( $('[name="size"]').val() );
});
</script>
```

Comment: but in your fiddle not any image is selected after page load

Comment: `chosen image` How do you determine what is the chosen image?

Comment: from the database. lets says that i want to edit the page and I want to show what was chosen before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Use the below one on click of image to get image id:

```
 $(this).attr("id")
```

1. To hightlight the chosen image (assuming that you will get image id from database but for testing hardcoded in fiddle) use:

> ```
> $(document).ready(function(){
> var id = "img1";
> $("#thumbs #"+id).addClass('border-highlight');
> });
> ```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9rFKB/21/)**</kbd>

**NOTE:** Added id's to `img` tag to test.

Comment: Hi, I don't want to alert the ID. I want it to be POST in this field: <input type="hidden" name="size">

Comment: you can use the id to post as per your requirement.

Comment: can you write me example please?

Comment: use the above code and change it according to your requirement. I didnt get you what is example?

Comment: let me explain again what I need: I have this code that send with field SIZE the name of the chosen image: "$('[name="size"]').val( $this.attr('src').substring($this.attr('src').lastIndexOf('/')+1) );"

instead of sending the name of the image I want to sent its ID

Comment: Use $(this).attr("id") to get image id. what is the problem that you are facing with this?

Comment: Image is not a input field, so how do I POST the image ID?

Comment: can I do this: $('[name="size"]') = $(this).attr("id"); ?

Comment: No use this: $("input[name='size']").val($(this).attr("id")); But make sure that you dont have duplicate inputs with name size.

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = $(this).attr("id");
```

or

```
var id = $(this).prop("id");
```

then use it like this

```
$("#" + id).val(....
```

for storing data you can use cookie localStorage and sessionStorage

Comment: like this: $('[name="size"]').var id = $(this).attr("id");  ? because if yes its not working... :/

Answer (score 0):

```
var img = $('#thumbs > img:nth-child(2)');
img.attr('class', 'border-highlight');
$('[name="animal"]').val( img.attr('src').substring(img.attr('src').lastIndexOf('/')+1) );
alert( $('[name="animal"]').val() );
```

The above code lets you specify which image you want highlighted in the 'thumbs' div by simply passing the child index value.  Just pass the id value you want to replace "2". [JsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9rFKB/22/)

Comment: thanks, but 1 thing - I don't want to alert the id. I want to POST it with field SIZE (which is hidden). how do I do that?

Comment: So you simply want to set the id value to an attribute called "size"?

`img.attr('size', $('[name="animal"]').val());`  and in your click function `$this.attr('size', $('[name="animal"]').val());`  Here is the JsFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/9rFKB/23/).  If you inspect the img elements after a click, you'll see the size attribute has been added with the id value.